# Patterns for disk cache clearing/size limit in PHP?

Tags: php, caching, design-patterns

My script fetches a lot of JPEG files over a slow connection. I store downloaded files in a local cache and re-use them until they're changed.

The question is: **how do I make sure that this cache is never larger than 16Mb (say)?**

I can clean it up when I want:

1. Calculate total size of all files in cache.
2. Delete some files until it's under 16Mb minus how much I need.

But what if two instances of the script do this? Both make sure 1Mb is free, then use 1Mb each, and the cache is 17Mb now. 16Mb rule is broken.

I know that I can make **"lazy cache"**: just clean it up from time to time. But a malicious user can trigger a lot of caching and exhaust disk space. This is a shared hosting, so no can do.

**The only solution I came up with (bad):**

Before storing anything, lock the whole cache, clean up the space needed, store file, unlock cache. Why bad: I'm caching a lot of files, so a lot of locking and a lot of cleaning up. Slow. (Also how do you lock/wait on locks in PHP?)

Comment: Do you know the filesize before fetching the file from the remote location ? if not you could clean up the cache dir, after fetching the file.

Comment: I do, but does that help? Two instances fetch 1Mb each, both make sure there's 1Mb free, both write down 1Mb => 2Mb used.

Comment: @himself Can you explain the cache is PHP generated HTML, source code, serialization data, JSON, or just normal static images?

Comment: @ajreal: Just images (well, other binary data sometimes).

Comment: @himself You should consider other CDN hosting like amazon S3, surely is affordable and cheaper than your current hosting ...

Comment: @ajreal: Wait, why? What's wrong with my hosting? I haven't told a bad thing about it yet:) 16Mb was, of course, just an example.

Comment: @himself Don't got me wrong, I should be refer to image hosting could use external domain (like CDN)

Comment: @ajreal: Well, uh, I'm not hosting images. This is just a temporary storage to speed up their downloading from other sources.

Answer (score 1):

Maby I misunderstood you - this looks too easy. If you don't have database avaliable - read database = some file with some data format.

Create a table in database with columns: filename, filesize, flag if file is still downloading(true/false).

When you get a new request to download a file - lock this table. Calculate SUM(filesize).

1. If it is less then 16MB minus new  filesize then add new entry to table. Change flag(of cource with lock/unlock before/after) after file is downloaded.
2. If it is more: look if you have some downloaded files you can delete and delete them while you don't have enough free space, then add entry to table.
3. If you can't free enough memory - deny this request/wait for some files to download.

Unlock table immidiately after each case - it should be locked only a few ms each time, so no waiting for anyone.

Comment: That's an interesting idea in that it makes locking easier, but isn't it the same otherwise? I still have to exclusively lock every time.

Comment: @himself: what is the problem with exclusive locks if they lock only for a few ms? Most applications that use MySql use locks if they are written correctly. File system locks are a bit worse, but most OS'es do it anyway.

Comment: There's a lot of files to cache, so I thought running a cleanup (exclusively locked, too) every time would introduce a bottleneck. It's not only a few ms because you're deleting files and inserting files inside it, and disk IO is slow.

Comment: Please, reread my post, you dont do *ANY* I/O operations while locked, you only read/write to the database wich should happen immidiately (well, it may be I/O if you don't use in-memory database, but it is really small and on any disk it will be fast). All files are downloaded outside of locks. If you need me to describe how to delete files outside of lock too - just say.

Comment: When you read/write the database, you're doing file I/O (unless it's memcached, but it's not). It's not "small" nor "large", but exactly the size of file you're reading. If you're reading 1.5Mb JPEG from the DB, you're reading 1.5Mb of data from disk. Database (not memory cached) doesn't change a thing here.

Comment: You don't store files in database, only their filename/filesize and one bit flag. It will never be large. That was the difference between my solution and yours: you only lock small database to read/write little information, then download your file without any locks to disk, not database, as you would without any locks/databases. Operations example for case (1): lock DB, search in DB(sum filesize), write new entry(filename/filesize/true flag) to DB, unlock DB, download file to some folder,lock DB, write to DB(change flag to false), unlock DB. As you can see downloading happens outside of locks.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Yeah, this seems to be an option. Although it takes out the simplicity of "cache == just a folder with files", but it might be easier to track access time this way. I'll think it through, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go so far as you are with the rules, but you can use the following:

[file_put_contents](http://www.php.net/file_put_contents) -

> LOCK_EX -  Acquire an exclusive lock on the file while proceeding to the
>   writing.

Create a .txt file somewhere, have your script try to acquire the contents. If there's a script already running, it will have the lock on the file so the new script won't be able to access the file. If you can't access the file, don't execute the code for caching.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a leaky bucket. You need to store lasttime(unix timestamp) and bucket(integer). Every time you store something you calculate the time-lapse since last save to cache, decrement this in seconds from bucket, then inc bucket by x of bytes. If the bucket is more then your capacity minus the jpeg-file sizes you delete the oldest objects to free desired space.